# Compare FALSE expression in Robot Framework Test Cases

Tags: robotframework

I'm having issue in negate the bool variable or comparison of FALSE against a bool variable to perform `Run Keyword If`

My Code is

```
Test Case
    ${isExist}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${element_Id}
    Run Keyword If     ${isExist} == false    click element ${cancelbtn}
```

Here I'm facing an Run time error

> Evaluating expression 'True and' failed: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF
>   while parsing (, line 1)

I tried the following comparison too

- `${isExist} == 'false'`
- `'${isExist}' == 'false'`
- `${isExist} == ${false}`
- `'${isExist}' == '${false}'`
- `!${isExist}`

Note: `log to console    ${isExist}` - It logs the appropriate Boolean value in the console window.

Comment: Where is the `and` coming from in your error?

Comment: @ILostMySpoon - I'm not sure from where its coming.

Comment: What does `${isExist}` evaluate to when logging to console?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get `Evaluating expression 'True and' failed: `  no matter what the actual value of `${isExist}`.  Can you show the actual line of code that gives that error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if `${isExist}` is a boolean, you can use `not`

```
Run Keyword If     not ${isExist}     ...
```

You can also compare to `${FALSE}` or `${TRUE}`:

```
Run Keyword If     ${isExist} is ${FALSE}    ...
Run Keyword If     ${isExist} is not ${TRUE}  ...
```

You say that `${isExist} == ${false}` doesn't work, but it will if `{isExist}` is indeed the boolean value `False`.

Note: `${FALSE}` and `${TRUE}` are variables defined by robot. They are briefly mentioned in the documentation in the section titled [Boolean and None/null variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#boolean-and-none-null-variables) in the robot framework user guide.